# Cannot get postgres to take a default value

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

If I defined a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  bhp NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  avatar_url VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'https://static.thenounproject.com/png/449586-200.png',
  owner INTEGER references owners(id)
);
```

and then I use `node-postgres`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) like so:

```
app.post("/api/v1/cars", (req, res) => {
  const { make, bhp, avatar_url } = req.body;
  console.log('Adding', { make, bhp, avatar_url });
  pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO cars (make, bhp, avatar_url) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
    [make, bhp, avatar_url],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
      }
      res.status(201).send(results);
    }
  );
});
```

and the write values look like this:

```
(5, mini, 5, null, null) // (id, make, bhp, avatar_url, owner)
```

but null does not result in the default value being set: How can I force it to take the default value if null (`undefined` in the js) is sent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace the undef value with `DEFAULT`

Comment: The column `avatar_url` allows `NULL` so  a  `NULL` value is acceptable and will override the `DEFAULT`. Your choices are don't include the column in the `INSERT` or use @clamp's suggestion.

Comment: @clamp Not quite sure what you mean. I can't pass the string 'DEFAULT' or that ends up getting saved?!

Comment: You mean in the application code, don't you...

Answer (score 0):

So, I took @Adrian Klaver's suggestion and did:

```
app.post("/api/v1/cars", (req, res) => {
  const { data } = req.body;
  console.log('Adding', data);

  const fields = Object.keys(data);
  const columns = fields.join(", ");
  const values = [];
  for(const field of fields) {
    const value = data[field];
    if(value) {
      values.push(value);
    }
  }

  const fullQuery = `INSERT INTO cars (${columns}) VALUES (${values.map((v, i) => `$${i+1}`).join(", ")})`;
  console.log('fullQuery', fullQuery);
  console.log('values', values);

  pool.query(
    fullQuery,
    values,
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('err', error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
      }
      res.status(201).send(results);
    }
  );
});
```